# Display coordinates from db in Google Maps

Tags: php, database, google-maps, coordinates

So after getting myself informed about how to retrieve x and y coordinates from my database and display them in Google Maps: I went to work. So to make a connection with my mySQL database is wrote this:

```
<?php
  $server     = '132.3.2.1.';
  $username   = 'you';
  $password   = 'notyou';
  $database   = 'youapp';
  $dsn        = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database";

  (This is all made up)
```

To retrieve the coordinates from my database and put them in a JSON string I wrote this:

```
<?php
  include 'config.php';
  try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM youapp");
    $youapp = $sth->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode( $youapp );
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

I am pretty sure that what I have coded up till now is correct. But I am not sure on the Google Maps part.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Beer Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    var map;
    function init() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          displayLocation(data[i]);
        }
      });
    }
    function makeRequest(url, callback) {
      var request;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      // IE6, IE5
      }
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
          callback(request);
        }
      }
      request.open("GET", url, true);
      request.send();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the function `makerequest` is a standard Ajax call. But I am not sure how to display the results in Google Maps. If anyone could look at my code to make a connection with my database and give some advice or something on how to display the results from the `makerequest` in Google Maps, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which kind of information does your database has?

Comment: My database stores x and y coordinates in double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks good except you are missing the function `displayLocation`. Just add this in there:

```
function displayLocation(item) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // might need to change item.lat/item.lng
        //  to match the column name in your DB
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
        map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Y i named the colums x and y so i would have to change that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this.

```
function displayLocation(item) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // might need to change item.lat/item.lng
        //  to match the column name in your DB
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
        map: map
    });
}
```